# Serializable Transaction for Checking, Inserting, and returning a value

Tags: mysql, database, serialization, transactions, psql

I am trying to check the database to see if the given name and manufacturer are present. If they are then return the product id. If they are not then insert them into the database, create a new productId, and return it. This query returns 0 when I print the value of product_id.

```
public int addProduct(String name, String manufacturer) throws SQLException{
    int productId = 0;
    Statement st = null;
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    try {
    st = this.connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(
    "BEGIN TRAN IF EXISTS (SELECT Products.name, Products.manufacturer FROM Products WITH (updlock, serializable) WHERE (Products.name = name AND Products.manufacturer = manufacturer) BEGIN INSERT INTO Products (product_id, name, category, manufacturer) VALUES (productId, name, null, manufacturer) END IF; COMMIT TRANSACTION;" );

    if(rs.next())
        productId = rs.getInt("product_id");
    else
        System.out.println("Product not added!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e);

    } finally {
        if (st != null) st.close();
    }
```

Comment: It would be extremely usual for [tag:psql] and [tag:mysql] both to be appropriate tags for the same question, and it seems possible that neither may be applicable here.  What database server platform is this question about?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading it wrong, but it looks like your SQL says to `insert if it is already there, and do nothing if it isn't there`.  Which would explain the `0` return.